# How can i resize the circle radius to fit the paragraph in it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to fit the paragraph and resize the circle radius .. can anyone look into this?

```css
#circle{
 background:#aaa;
 height:300px;
 width:300px;
  border-radius:50%;
 text-align:center;
  /*line-height:300px;*/

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div id="circle">
    <span class="text-center"><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p></span></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `position: center;`??

Comment: and `//` is not how you comment out in CSS, you need to use `/*` and `*/` to add comments in CSS.

Comment: yes the posiiton property doesnt take any value="center" and in the codepen.io which i made this code it accepts some how accepts  this  `//` commenting but i will start using `/*` and `*/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**: Using the CSS transform property you can be more accurate with center positioning using relative sized objects.

Of course you could use some javascript to get the height of the paragraph and position it accurately regardless of content.

I did remove the span and a div, didn't see a need for them.

```css
.container{
  background:#aaa;
 height:300px;
 width:300px;
  border-radius:50%;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}

.container p {
 position: absolute;
  
 top: 47%; 
  
  /* used 47% rather than 50% 
  becuase items tend to "sink" visually, 
  so placing it slightly higher is a good thing. */
  
transform: translateY(-50%); 

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>      </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox to center the copy inside your circle and some padding to hopefully contain it. Please note that you'll have to use browser prefixes for flexbox, depending on what browsers you need to support (more info: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#circle {
 background: #aaa;
 border-radius: 50%;
 text-align:center;
 height:300px;
 width:300px;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
 padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="circle">
        <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can depend the width and height of div on p or span only by css

Check from the source code and you will see your div is square or rectangle it will never be circle it is only shown as circle cause of radius

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
      <div id="circle">
    <span class="text-center"><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p></span></div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
        #circle{
 background:#aaa;
 height:auto;
 width:30vw;
  border-radius:100%;
 text-align:center;
}
p{
   height:auto;
 width:30vw;
  border-radius:100%;
 text-align:center;
  background:red;

}
```

Comment: Yes i agree that my initial shape was square/rectangle so with pure css it isn't going to work and need to try with jQuery but still would like to wait for some more suggestions

Comment: I don't think so even I update the code and give border radius for p tag and bg is red but it doesn't influence the text